# How to render the html stored in the database to an ejs page

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, ejs

I believe this is an easy one but can't seem to figure it out.

I have **Quilljs** editor installed in my nodejs/express webapp and it is storing my description in the mysql db as `<p><strong>This is the quill data. How are we doing dev?</strong></p>`.

Now my ejs page looks like this :

```
<% data.forEach(function(d,index){ %>
   <p> <%= d.description %> </p>
<% }) %>
```

but this obviously renders the data as stored in the db(with `p` and `strong` tags).

### What I tried:

- tried using `<pre>` so that the formatting remains intact(just newbie try).
- tried `.html()` and `.load()` methods of jquery to update the data as HTML but for no use.

How can I convert this to html? so that the formatted text prints the resultant HTML and not the source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `<%-` instead of `<%=`

```
<% data.forEach(function(d,index){ %>
   <p> <%- d.description %> </p>
<% }) %>
```

You could look about tags paragraph to see more use about `<%=` or `<%-` in [ejs docs](https://ejs.co/#docs)

Note: If you do this, be careful about XSS problem.
And you'll need a [sanitize-html](https://github.com/apostrophecms/sanitize-html#readme) to keep your html save.

### EDIT1

You don't need to assign it to new variable.

```
<% data.forEach(function(d,index){ %>
  <% if (d.description.length > 75) { %>
    <p> <%- d.description.substring(0, 75) %> </p>
  <% } else { %>
    <p> <%- d.description %> </p>
  <% }%>
<% }) %>
```

Comment: That works! Thanks.Can I use the `<%-` in scriptlet tags? something like this:  `<%  <%-  d.description  %>  %>`? What is the alternative?

Comment: why do you want to do it?

Comment: I want to limit the description to say 75 letters. Therefore, I want to perform some js operations on the html formatted text such as : `<% var theDesc = <%- d.description %>;  var newStr;  if(theDesc.length >75) { newStr = theDesc.substring(0,75);  } else newStr = theDesc;  %>`. Is it possible?

Comment: obviously if  I remove the `<%- %>` around the d.description in the code above, it will work. But then it renders  the variable like this `&gt;p&lt; Some text &gt;/p&lt;`. This is the whole thing I'm trying to do.

Comment: Thanks a ton for this mate. I am pretty new to templating engines with NodeJS. And should've searched the doc for this. Thanks again for your time.

Answer (score 1):

DON'T SAVE HTML.

This can take a lot of problems to you.
Try to make some arbitrary data structure like json and print that with your EJS.

Comment: As i said Sir, I'm using quiil editor and it gives me those HTML tags to keep the styling/formatting intact. Can you please show me some methods or link me to related articles/docs/blogs/anything to achieve what you are saying? That would be a lot of help. Thanks.

Comment: You can preserve the format using some AST (abstract syntax tree)